# Trying to store multiple data (row) but it only create 1 row in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to store array data(saving multiple row) but on single row is being store in my database.

here's my form,

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'warehouse1.store']) !!}
@foreach($order->orderItems as $orderItem)
    <input type="number" name="stock_in_qty[]" id="stock_in_qty_{{$orderItem->id}}" class="form-control stock_in_qty" min="1" value="{{$orderItem->quantity}}" data-max="{{$orderItem->quantity}}" onkeyup="check(this);"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $orderItem_id = {{$orderItem->id}};
            $('#stock_in_qty_'+$orderItem_id).on('mouseup keyup', function () {
            $(this).val(Math.min({{$orderItem->quantity}}, Math.max(1, $(this).val())));
        });
    </script>
    {{ Form::date('delivery_date[]',today(), ['class' => 'form-control date', 'style' => 'width:200px;','required']) }}
    {!! Form::text('delivery_note[]', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}                  
    {!! Form::hidden('order_id[]', $order->id) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('order_item_id[]', $orderItem->id ) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('company_id[]', $order->company->id) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('stock_out_qty[]',null) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('transfer_to[]', null) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('user_id[]',auth()->user()->id ) !!}
@endforeach

{!! Form::submit('Add to stocks', [ 'class'=>'btn btn-info']) !!} 
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Here's my store function**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    for($i=0; $i<= count($input['stock_in_qty']); $i++) {

        if(empty($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['stock_in_qty'][$i])) continue;

        $acceptItem = [
            'order_id' => $input['order_id'][$i],
            'order_item_id' => $input['order_item_id'][$i],
            'delivery_date' => $input['delivery_date'][$i],
            'company_id' => $input['company_id'][$i],
            'stock_in_qty' => intval($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]),
            'stock_out_qty' => $input['stock_out_qty'][$i],
            'transfer_to' => $input['transfer_to'][$i],
            'delivery_note' => $input['delivery_note'][$i],
            'user_id' => $input['user_id'][$i]  
        ];


        Warehouse1stocks::create($acceptItem);
        return redirect()->route('orders.index');
    }
}
```

**dd($acceptItem); result**

[image]

**dd($input) result**

[image]

what do you think is the possible cause of this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `dd` means __dump and die__. Your script dies after first output. __Learn__ what function does before using it.

Comment: yes even I remove it it only save 1 row. that's just for me to see if I am grabbing the rows. well probably that may cause a confusion. I will remove it in my question

Comment: `return` __stops__ execution of a function. Are you sure what you do in your code?

Comment: You are stoping the execution at the first iteration i hope this return will comes after for loop

Comment: can do `dd($input['stock_in_qty'])` and post here i hope you are in wrong logic

Comment: Can you verify the `count($input['stock_in_qty'])` if bigger then 1? and it should be `<` and not `<=` (in the `for` condition)

Comment: @Lito Could you please expand `stock_in_qty` array so we can see the contents therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your controller method to this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $items = [];

    for($i=0; $i < count($input['stock_in_qty']); $i++) {

        if(empty($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['stock_in_qty'][$i])) continue;

        $acceptItem = [
            'order_id' => $input['order_id'][$i],
            'order_item_id' => $input['order_item_id'][$i],
            'delivery_date' => $input['delivery_date'][$i],
            'company_id' => $input['company_id'][$i],
            'stock_in_qty' => intval($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]),
            'stock_out_qty' => $input['stock_out_qty'][$i],
            'transfer_to' => $input['transfer_to'][$i],
            'delivery_note' => $input['delivery_note'][$i],
            'user_id' => $input['user_id'][$i]  
        ];


        array_push($items, Warehouse1stocks::create($acceptItem));
    }

    dd($items);

    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
}
```

Because as your code clearly shows below after the creation first `acceptItem` you will be redirected to the `route('orders.index')` and not create the other `acceptItems`

```
for($i=0; $i<= count($input['stock_in_qty']); $i++) {

    if(empty($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['stock_in_qty'][$i])) continue;

    $acceptItem = [
        'order_id' => $input['order_id'][$i],
        'order_item_id' => $input['order_item_id'][$i],
        'delivery_date' => $input['delivery_date'][$i],
        'company_id' => $input['company_id'][$i],
        'stock_in_qty' => intval($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]),
        'stock_out_qty' => $input['stock_out_qty'][$i],
        'transfer_to' => $input['transfer_to'][$i],
        'delivery_note' => $input['delivery_note'][$i],
        'user_id' => $input['user_id'][$i]  
    ];


    Warehouse1stocks::create($acceptItem);
    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
}
```

So you need to move the `return` statement out of the for loop.

Comment: Please add explanation on what you changed (moving the return out of the `for` loop and creating array of added item) and beware of the `dd` inside as the comment on the question said...

Comment: Hi @kellymandem it is still saving 1 row basically the first row. the result of the dd(items) is->   array:1 [▼
  0 => Warehouse1stocks {#354 ▶}
]

Comment: @Lito have you confirmed that all the content in `$input['stock_in_qty']` passes this test `(empty($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]))`

Comment: Hi @kellymandem the stock_in_qty has values. upon testing dd($input) the result is,   "stock_in_qty" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "215"
    1 => "123"
    2 => "214"
    3 => "543"
  ]

Comment: ah wait @kellymandem i think its workings! its my mistake because I did not put the         Warehouse1stocks::create($acceptItem);
        return redirect()->route('orders.index'); out of the loop. but I noticed the last row is being save twice

Comment: But if i run dd($items) it displays only 4 rows which is correct, array:4 [▼
  0 => Warehouse1stocks {#354 ▶}
  1 => Warehouse1stocks {#350 ▶}
  2 => Warehouse1stocks {#357 ▶}
  3 => Warehouse1stocks {#359 ▶}
]
 but if i check my data base the last row is being save twice.

Comment: @Lito am glad I could help though an upvote and marking as the accepted answer would be nice.

Comment: @kellymandem what do you think why the last row is being save twice?

Comment: @Lito my mistake; this line `for($i=0; $i<= count($input['stock_in_qty']); $i++) {` should be like this `for($i=0; $i < count($input['stock_in_qty']); $i++) {`. That is the reason the last row is being saved twice. Notice the change from **$i <= count($input['stock_in_qty'])** to **$i < count($input['stock_in_qty'])**.

Comment: Hi @kellymandem actually my mistake again :( I wasn't able to delete the Warehouse1stocks::create($acceptItem); outside the loop that's why the last record is saving twice. Thank you so much for your help!!! :)